# Form with has_many (it can have N many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I have these two models:

**User** which **has_many** Languages **through proficiencies**

And

**Languages** which **has_many** Users **through proficiencies**

When I have a form to create a new User, I am wondering how I let the User to add N languages to his signup.  So, having somehow a dynamic form that lets the user to add as many languages as he wants.

How could I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Watch these three Railscasts for a solid understanding of what you're trying to do:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/73-complex-forms-part-1

http://railscasts.com/episodes/74-complex-forms-part-2

http://railscasts.com/episodes/75-complex-forms-part-3

They deal with it exactly.

Comment: Jonny, thanks for the answer, but those doesn't deal with has_many through.

Comment: The problem with those screencasts is that they are outdated and the syntax is different now. But by the code (I havent watched the screencasts) seems Ryan Bates does some sort of what the OP needs. You just need a way to select multiple laguages id, and then in the controller create proficienties for each language passed.

Comment: The Railscasts give you the basis you need to work out how to do the implementation you want. Adding n-options to a form is a relatively common requirement, after that it's a case of working out how to make it work with your `has_many :through` implementation. And yeah, some of the syntax will be out of date, but I don't think that makes the screencasts 'outdated'

Answer (score 0):

You can use either cocoon https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon or nested_form https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form

These will let you dynamically add and remove sets of fields for the languages in your User form.

Or you could use chosen - https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails - to give a nice auto-complete multi select box.